# How to add user inputs in python?

Tags: python, addition, user-input

I'm doing a problem where I need to find the total of the user input. But when I do it, it only outputs the last user input. Here's what I got.

```
#Ask for the number of days of weather data they have
weather = int(input("How many days of weather data do you have? "))

total=0
x=1

#Ask what the rainfall was for each day
while(x<=weather):
    temp_weather = input("What is the rainfall for day " +str(x)+"? ")
    x=x+1

#Add the total rainfall output
while(temp_weather>total):
    total= total+temp_weather
    print("The total rainfall for the period was "+ str(weather))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp_weather` is being overwritten every subsequent time the user inputs information.  The inputs before the last one are being recorded and then discarded.

Try something like:

```
#Ask what the rainfall was for each day
while(x<=weather):
    total += input("What is the rainfall for day " +str(x)+"? ")
    x += 1

print("The total rainfall for the period was "+ str(total))
```

Note that I changed "weather" to "total" on the last line because I assumed that's what you intended!

Answer (score 0):

`temp_weather` should store a list of values. Which means it has to be a list. In your current code, the `while` loop iterates `x` times but the `temp_weather` variable is over written every time. And hence it just stores the last value.

Declare `temp_weather` as a list like this:

```
temp_weather = []
```

Now, change your code as:

```
while x <= weather:
    y = input("What is the rainfall for day " +str(x)+"? ")
    temp_weather.append(int(y))
    x=x+1
```

Now, `temp_weather` will have a list of values. To get the total, you can just use the `sum()` method:

```
total = sum(temp_weather)
```